# RCD snubber circuit

Tags: triac, snubber

I'm designing a timed fan switch using an 800V 25A (overkill) TRIAC with an RCD snubber circuit with 120VAC source.  The circuit is shown at the TRIAC shut off at I_hold of 50mA.  The load current at shut off is negative with respect to the source voltage because of the 0.8 power factor and inductive current lag.

The purpose of the left diode is that when the triac shuts off, the source doesn't go through the TRIAC and charges the capacitor very quickly then about 2 microseconds later, when the TRIAC turns back on, the capacitor discharges through the resistor to generate a lasting latching current in the tTRIAC. (I'm actually using a wirewound resistor to limit the current rise time.)

All of the RCD snubber references I have seen only show the single left diode.  My question is that at the next half cycle turn off the residual current will be positive and the source will be negative.  The negative voltage cannot traverse the left anode to cathode diode.  To charge the capacitor in this situation I think I need a second reverse parallel diode, but I have never seen this.

[image]

Comment: You can use the editor toolbar CircuitLab button to draw your schematic you can use the **Save and Insert** button to insert a PNG of the schematic into the post along with an edit link. There's no need for a CircuitLab account. No screengrab. No grid. It alsow means that others can copy and paste your schematic for further editing.

Comment: Not waist to use too much overrated triac. A 25A triac can have 100mA holding/turning-off current, so lot of energy can stay accumulated in steel during turning off.

Answer (score 0):

The diodes short each other (and the resistor) out, leaving ±V<sub>F</sub> drop.  You basically have a capacitor across the TRIAC, and little damping effect.

You can't use that network on an AC circuit.  Or put another way: a pair of unidirectional RCD snubbers reduces to an RC with no diodes, not two diodes in parallel.  So, just stick with the usual RC.

An alternative is a clamp snubber, which rather than using RCD components, can simply be a TVS or MOV.  More likely MOV, given the stresses of mains power.

Snubber discussions can be found here: 
[Snubber Circuit capacitor question | EEVblog Forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/snubber-circuit-capacitor-question/) 
[snubber 3 different 230V AC motors in a record cleaning machine | EEVblog Forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/snubber-3-different-230v-ac-motors-in-a-record-cleaning-machine/) 
as well as numerous topics here.

Comment: When triac is off the left diode is forward biased and the right diode is reversed biased and blocked.  The source then charges the capacitor, and the triac should have no effect as it is (for a couple of usec) an open circuit.  I'm not worried about voltage spikes as I have a separate MOV/TVS

Comment: You asked why you haven't seen this circuit, and I explained it's redundant: extra parts can be removed. If there is more to your circuit, that would've affected this answer, you should've added that to your question in the first place. We can only answer based on information as-given. As an answer now exists, and if you feel your underlying question hasn't been answered, you can ask a new question, with all relevant information included.  If we're done here, you can [vote and accept](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) an answer. Cheers!

Comment: My concern, as I mentioned, is in the next half cycle when the triac shuts off again the source is negative and the load current is positive.  The negative source cannot traverse the single now reverse biased diode to charge the capacitor.  Thanks for the reply.